# Access services inside a regular class

Tags: php, symfony, localization, twig

I have a regular class in my Symfony2 project:

```
    class RangeColumn extends Column{
        //...
    }
```

Now inside this class is a render function, in which I'd like to use Twig or the Translation Service of Symfony2 to render a specific template. How do I access this services in a proper way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection). It's a really simple concept.

You should simply pass (inject) needed services to your class.

If dependencies are **obligatory** pass them in a **constructor**. If they're **optional** use **setters**.

You might go further and delegate construction of your class to the dependency injection container (make a service out of it).

Services are no different from your "regular" class. It's just that their construction is delegated to the container.

Answer (score 10):

Code example:

```
<?php

class MyRegularClass
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function myFunction()
    {
        $this->translator->trans('sentence_to_translate');
    }
}
```

And if you want your class to become a service:
In your services.yml file located in your bundle,

```
parameters:
    my_regular_class.class: Vendor\MyBundle\Classes\MyRegularClass

services:
    mybundle.classes.my_regular_class:
        class: %my_regular_class.class%
        arguments: [@translator]
```

For more details, see the chapter about the Symfony2 [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: Dependency Injection tag is `@translator.default` by Symfony 2.6, the `@translator` tag refers to LoggingTranslator now.