# Using custom logger service in AuthenticationHandler class in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, config, monolog

**In brief I am trying to use a logger service that I defined inside a custom handler service.**

**My config.yml**

```
services:
authentication_handler:
    class: Panasonic\LoginBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler
    arguments: [ @custom_logger ]

custom_logger:
    class: Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [login]
    calls:
        - [ pushHandler, [ @custom_logger_stream ]]

custom_logger_stream:
    class: Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler
    arguments: [ %kernel.logs_dir%/test.log, 30, 200 ]
```

The "services:" is well indented in my code, dnt worry.

**My Bundle/Handler/AuthenticationHandler**

```
namespace Panasonic\LoginBundle\Handler;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

private $custom_logger;

public function __constructor(Logger $custom_logger)
{
    $this->custom_logger = $custom_logger;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request,
                                        TokenInterface $token)
{
    $log = $this->custom_logger;

    $log->addWarning('Foo');
    $log->addError('Bar');
    die;

    //        var_dump($token); die;
    //        var_dump($request->getSession()); die;
}
}
```

I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addWarning() on a non-object in ... Panasonic\LoginBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler.php on line 22
```

Note: I am aware I should return a response in onAuthenticationSuccess, it's in fact uncomplete, but I know it works, I got results from the var_dumps.

**I guess the injection is not ok, how should it be done? I can't figure out what to do here. Please help**

the references I checked:
[Access services inside a regular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953721/symfony2-access-services-inside-a-regular-class)

http://martinsikora.com/symfony2-and-dependency-injection

Comment: I think the error is in custom_logger: class: Monolog\LoggerSymfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger and should have used LoggerInterface in my handler. I solved my problem with the link PéCé gave by readapting my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your contructor name... I guess it is not called...

```
public function __construct()
{
    // ...
}
```

I've written an article exactly explaining how to achieve that : http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/04/set-up-specific-log-file-for.html

Comment: Thank you, your blog post helped me in locating my mistakes. Nice example with clean code.